# Java - Converting Big Endian binary String to Little Endian

Tags: java, binary, endianness

I'm trying to make a Java program that receives a binary String in Big Endian, like this: "11001100111111110001010011000000". The program should output the same String, but converted to Little Endian.
What can I have done is this:

```
private String toLittleEndian(String binaryString) {

    while(binaryString.length() < 32)
        binaryString = "0" + binaryString;

    String result = "";

    for (int i = binaryString.length() - 1; i > 0; i -= 8)
    {
        String str = binaryString.substring(i - 7, i + 1);
        result += str;
    }

    //result = result.substring(zeros_added, result.length());
    return result;
}
```

But it doesn't give me the expected result when I call to

```
Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2);
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: What input are you passing this, what result are you expecting, and what result are you getting?

Comment: I'm passing it "11101001110000011001011011011", and I'm expecting that the result, interpreted as an unsigned int number, will be 462864873. I'm getting -617465827

Comment: If I use Long.parseUnsignedLong I'm getting 3677501469

Comment: Well, -617465827 seems like the correct answer to me.  Why do you expect 462864873?

Comment: Because it's a requirement of this task

Comment: You're required to produce the wrong answer?  The correct answer is -617465827.

Comment: The integers are unsigned, so I can't give a negative result

Comment: OK, well for a start, integers in Java are signed.  Whether you like it or not.  But if you want the unsigned version of the answer, then it's 3677501469, as you've already discovered.  So your program is not doing anything wrong.  Your program is fine.  The only thing that's wrong is that you want to have 462864873 as an answer.  The answer is NOT 462864873.

Answer (score 0):

The binary string `11001100111111110001010011000000` does not fit into `int`. Try with `long`

```
String binaryString="11001100111111110001010011000000";
long value =  Long.parseLong(binaryString, 2);
```

Comment: I have already tried it, but it returns 3677501469, and I'm expecting it to return 462864873.

Comment: Huh?  32 bits doesn't fit into a 32 bit integer?  Are you sure?

Comment: @DavidWallace, Yes,  It needs maximum 31 bits.

Comment: Of course 32 bits fits into 32 bits.  It just happens to represent a negative integer, not a positive one.

Comment: @DavidWallace, At this case it does not give you negative integer. It will throw `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Comment: What will?  All OP's code does is String manipulation.  How can it possibly throw a NumberFormatException?